# access codeigniter 3 (Appserv) from another computer locally

Tags: codeigniter, remote-access

I'm trying to access my site from another computer with Codeigniter 3 running on Appserv; but unable to.

I set the base_url as http://192.168.1.1/site/ in my application/config.php but still can't access the site.

Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using Windows, open your start menu and type firewall with advanced settings and add rules. Add a TCP with port selected with value 80 and save it.

Change your base_url to http://localhost/.

Open cmd and type ipconfig to see your local ip.

Make sure you have both computer/device is connected in the same local network.

If everything’s clear, open your host IP on the 2nd device browser address.

Comment: It worked!! thanks. for windows 10 user add to the above

    Select TCP for Does this rule apply to TCP or UDP.
    Select Specific local ports, and enter the TCP port to allow, then click Next.
    Note:  See Using the SQL Error Log to Determine the SQL Port. The standard SQL port is 1433, but can be different.
    Ensure Allow the connection is selected, then click Next.
    Select When to apply the rule (Domain, Private, or Public), then click Next.
    Enter a Name and optional Description, then click Finish.